# why AFNetworking get unsupported url when putting '|' pipe sign in the url

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-places-api, afnetworking-2

I've been using AFNetworking for a while and ran into a bizarre issue today.
I'm do a GET request using AFNetworking with Google Places API

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=21.283974,-157.836222&radius=1600&types=food|bar|cafe&key=myownapikeyhere
```

the places nearby search api uses `type` restriction to constrain the result you can get from the api. [see document](http://api.https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/search)

the way you do it is to have parameter `types=type1|type2|type3|etc`, the type1, type2, type3 are the types of places you want fetch with the url.
I managed to get results when I paste the url into browser and request it. but whenever I use it with `AFNetworking`, the `'|'` sign seems to break it. It throws an `unsupported url` error.

Is there a reason with this issue? Any suggestion would be helpful.

Thanks!

Comment: when I replaces `|` with `%7C`, the encoded version. it works, seems like the AFNetworking does not encode `|` by itself?

Comment: yes, I'm building the URL by myself. I'll try your suggestion, might be a better solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you building this URL yourself? If you used the parameters of a AFNetworking `GET` request, I believe it would percent escape it properly. But if you build the URL yourself, you're not letting AFNetworking do the necessary percent escaping.

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];

NSDictionary *params = @{@"location" : @"21.283974,-157.836222",
                         @"radius"   : @1600,
                         @"types"    : @"food|bar|cafe",
                         @"key"      : @"myownapikeyhere"};

[manager GET:@"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json" parameters:params success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"responseObject = %@", responseObject);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"error = %@", error);
}];
```

Comment: thank you Rob! Btw, is there any suggested best practice when using AFNetworking?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by suggested best practice. If you're availing yourself of `AFHTTPRequestOperationManager` or `AFHTTPSessionManager`, that's a pretty good start. Likewise, using it like above gets you out of the idiosyncrasies of building URLs and forming requests.

Answer (score 2):

It is too simple. Just replace the `|` with `%7C`

```
NSString *string = @"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=21.283974,-157.836222&radius=1600&types=food|bar|cafe&key=myownapikeyhere";

NSString *newString = [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"|" withString:@"%7C"];
```